# Ошибка get-запроса к api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, error404

Учусь и практикуюсь, повторял процесс создания интернет-магазина и наткнулся на 404 ошибку:

GET http://localhost:3001/api/basket/getone net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

либо пишет 404 not found. Таких ошибок несколько на get-запросы висит, на fetch-ах. Понимаю, о чем говорит ошибка, не могу понять как починить. Запросы проверил, написаны правильно, cors проверил.  БД тоже подключена правильно. Фаервол винды отключать пробовал, ничего не изменилось. Склонировал готовый репозиторий, та же самая ошибка.

Готовый код человека за которым повторял: https://github.com/tokmakov/javascript-shop

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=firewall+windows

Comment: Фаервол винды отключать пробовал, ничего не изменилось

Comment: ещё есть антивирусы и прочее доброносное п.о.